# Can not close my Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have my class in `Android` who `extends Dialog`

```
public class DialogSearch extends Dialog{

    public ImageButton imageButtonCancel ;


    public DialogSearch(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        setContentView(R.layout.finddialog);

        imageButtonCancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFindCancel);
        imageButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //hide();
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        this.show();
    }
}
```

this is not my `ActivityClass`, I can instanciate from my `ActivityClass` but when I click `imageButtonCancel` to close i doesn't work. I tryed both `hide()` and `close()` methods.

**up date**

this is my R.Layout.finddialog

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/editTextFind"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="write here"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonFindSearch"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextFind"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/find_icone"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
     />   

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonFindCancel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupeFind"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel_icone"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButtonFindSearch"

     />   


</RelativeLayout>
```

**up date**

I am calling it from my `ActivityClass`

```
public class mapActivity extends Activity {


    private ImageButton buttonSearch ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        buttonSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearchMain) ;   

         buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                 dialogSearch = new DialogSearch(mapActivity.this,R.style.FullHeightDialog); // this for not display dialog title part
            }
        });

    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: is onClick event is firing when you click on imageButton? put a debug point  there...

Comment: No there is no prblem when I click but does not do any thing

Comment: post your R.layout.finddialog xml file...

Comment: where you are using DialogSearch and how? can you post part of that code? I have tried your code. it is dismissing for me well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this... use onCreate() method...

```
public class DialogSearch extends Dialog {
    public DialogSearch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // hides title bar...
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.finddialog);

        ImageButton imageButtonCancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFindCancel);
        imageButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // hide();
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this and I am using the second constructor

Comment: @RiadSaadi I said override onCreate() method in Dialog. not onCreate() method of Activity. see my code...

Answer (score 1):

Try  `DialogSearch.this.dismiss();`

Comment: I tryed this, and doesn't close my Dialog